# Помогите упростить код

Tags: jquery, carousel

Привет всем! Недавно начал познавать мир jQuery и его магию, и состряпал алгоритм для ротатора картинок. Все работает, к моему удивлению, но я бы не проч узнать совета, как сократить мой код, сделать его чище... Просмотрите пожалуйста, есть ли метод упросить мою псанину? Повторюсь, все работает отлично.
Вот что у меня есть:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $slide = $('.slide').hide(); 
   $nextBtn = $('#nextBtn');
   $prevBtn = $('#prevBtn');
   $numberOfSlides = $('.slide').length;
   thumbnails = false;
   linkThumbnails = true;
   slideNum = 0;
   slides = [];
   for(i = 1; i <= $numberOfSlides; i++){
      slides.push('#slide'+i);
   };

   primeSlide = slides[slideNum];
   $(primeSlide).show();
   function onClickUp(){
      if (slideNum < slides.length){
         slideNum++;
         var slide = slides[slideNum];
         var prevSlide = slides[slideNum-1];
         $(slide).fadeIn('slow');
         $(prevSlide).fadeOut('slow').delay(200);
         if (slideNum == slides.length){
            slideNum = 0;
            slide = slides[slideNum];
            $(slide).fadeIn('slow');
         }
      }else{ alert('mistake somewhere'); }
   };
   function onClickDown(){
      if (slideNum === 0){
         slideNum = 0;
         $('.slide').eq(slideNum).fadeOut('slow');
         slideNum --;
         $('.slide').eq(slideNum).fadeIn('slow');
         if(slideNum < 0) {
            slideNum = $numberOfSlides -1;
         }
      }else if (slideNum > 0){
         $('.slide').eq(slideNum).fadeOut('slow');
         slideNum --;
         $('.slide').eq(slideNum).fadeIn('slow');
      }   
   };
   $nextBtn.on('click', function () {
      onClickUp();
      $('.thumbnail').removeClass('active'); changeThumb();
      $('.link').removeClass('active'); changeLink();
   });
   $prevBtn.on('click', function () {
      onClickDown();
      $('.thumbnail').removeClass('active');
      changeThumb();
      $('.link').removeClass('active');  changeLink();
   });

   clearTimeout();
   pause = 7000;
   stop = false;

   $('.slider').mouseenter(function(){stop = true; });
   $('.slider').mouseleave(function(){stop = false;});

   function tick() {
      if(!stop){
         onClickUp(); 
         $('.thumbnail').removeClass('active'); 
         changeThumb();
         $('.link').removeClass('active');  
         changeLink();                            
      }
   };

   setInterval(tick, pause); //ЗАПУСКАЕТ АВТОМАТИЧЕСКОЕ ПЕРЕКЛЮЧЕНИЕ

   myArrayImg = [];
   for(i=1; i <= $numberOfSlides; i++){
      myArrayImg.push('slide_'+i+'.png');
   }
   for(i = 0; i < myArrayImg.length; i++ ){
      if(thumbnails){
         $('.thumbnailWrap').append('<div class="thumbnail" id="thumb'+(i+1)+'"><img src="img/'+myArrayImg[i]+'"></div>');
      }else if (!thumbnails & linkThumbnails){
         $('#linkWrap').append('<div class="link" id="link'+(i+1)+'"></div>');  
      }
   }
   myThumbArray = [];
   for(i=1; i <= $numberOfSlides; i++){
      myThumbArray.push('#thumb'+i);
   }
   function changeThumb(){
      var slide = slideNum+1;
      $('.thumbnail').eq(0).addClass('active');
      if(slideNum){
         $.when(slide).then($('#thumb'+slide).addClass('active').focusin());
      }
      if(slideNum > 0){
         $('.thumbnail').eq(0).removeClass('active');
      }
   }
   changeThumb();

   function changeLink(){
      var slide = slideNum+1;
      $('.link').eq(0).addClass('active');
      if(slideNum){
         $.when(slide).then($('#link'+slide).addClass('active'));
      }
      if(slideNum > 0){
         $('.link').eq(0).removeClass('active');
      }
   }
   changeLink();
});
```

Не судите очень сторого, только только начал в это все вникать. Спасибо!

Comment: вот ссылка на сайт где я его использовал http://gamingport.tovstyga.ca/

Answer (score 2):

На исчерпывающий ответ не претендую, но всё же:

0) Захардкожены все DOM-элементы

1) Засоряете глобальную область видимости, забывая про `var` (две карусели на странице просто сколлапсируют)

2) Каша с обращениям к слайдам, то `$('.slide').eq(slideNum)`, то `slide = slides[slideNum];$(slide)`

3) Смысл присваивать `slide` два раза?

```
slideNum++;
var slide = slides[slideNum];
...
if (slideNum == slides.length){
    slideNum = 0;
    slide = slides[slideNum];
```

4) Зачем это:

```
  if (slideNum === 0){
     slideNum = 0;
```

5) При `stop=true` просто не меняете слайды, но таймер продолжает работать (согласен, спорный момент. В хороших практиках, правда, рекомендуют использовать вложенный `setTimeout` вместо `setInterval`)

6) Это где используется:

```
myThumbArray = [];
for(i=1; i <= $numberOfSlides; i++){
  myThumbArray.push('#thumb'+i);
}
```

7) В `changeThumb` какие-то непонятные манипуляции с первой превью

Comment: Весьма признателен. На все вопросы "Зачем" я не могу дать четкого ответа, но если оно там появилось, без него не работло =) А может просто из-за незнания что его там не должно быть я просто добавил.

Comment: Вот не поверю, что без пункта 4 не работало :)

Answer (score 0):

Код действительно массивен, начал читать, первые строчек двадцать тянут на опции, где вместо явного указания селекторов DOM элементов было бы замечательно заменить на переменные которые передаются из вне. Дальше идут методы и слушатели событий, что явно указывает на структура некого кластера(виджета/класса/плагина).

И если у вас уже достаточно опыта что бы написать то что действительно работает, то я бы посоветовал вам воспользоваться функционалом jQuery под названием jQuery.widget(). Какие преимущества?

1. вы сможете применять свои наработки на разных проектах со схожим функционалом
2. применять свой виджет к неограниченному количеству элементов на странице
3. применять свой виджет к неограниченному количеству элементов на странице
4. ваш код сразу станет значительно чише и понятнее вам самим
5. такой код легче поддерживать и расширять его возможности в зависимости от входных параметров

Вот пример структуры виджета:

```
(function( $ ) {
  $.widget( "demo.multi", {

    // Здесь задается список настроек и их значений по умолчанию
    options: { 
      clear: null
    },

    // Функция, вызываемая при активации виджета на элементе
    _create: function() {
    },

    // Этот метод вызывается для изменения настроек плагина
    _setOption: function( key, value ) {
      switch( key ) {
        case "clear":
          // предпринимаем действия по изменению свойства clear
          break;
      }

      // В jQuery UI 1.8, можно делегировать задачи методу
      // _setOption родительскому плагину:
      $.Widget.prototype._setOption.apply( this, arguments );

      // А начиная с UI 1.9 для этого достаточно вызвать метод _super
      this._super( "_setOption", key, value );
    },

    // деструктор - метод, который будет вызван при удалении плагина с элемента.
    // Он нужен чтобы очистить элемент от всех модификаций, сделанных плагином
    // (удалить вспомогательные классы, атрибуты и элементы)
    destroy: function() {
      // В jQuery UI 1.8, можно делегировать задачу очищения элемента
      // родительскому плагину
      $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
      // In jQuery UI 1.9 and above, you would define _destroy instead of destroy and not call the base method
    }
  });
}( jQuery ) );
```

Более подробнее можно почитать тут: [$.widget()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_UI)

Так же можно посмотреть в сторону классов на ES6: [ES-2015 CLASS](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class)